# How do I pass start date and end date parameter to SQL using Excel VBA?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, stored-procedures, vba

I have the following code which works when I enter a customer ID from the Northwind DB example in Excel cell D2 (e.g) ALFKI:

[image: excel screen]

This is my Excel VBA code which works so far:

```vb
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim WSP1 As Worksheet
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Contacting SQL Server..."

' Remove any values in the cells where we want to put our Stored Procedure's results.
Dim rngRange As Range
Set rngRange = Range(Cells(8, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).EntireRow
rngRange.ClearContents

' Log into our SQL Server, and run the Stored Procedure
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
cmd.ActiveConnection = con

' Set up the parameter for our Stored Procedure
' (Parameter types can be adVarChar,adDate,adInteger)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("CustomerID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, Range("D2").Text)

Application.StatusBar = "Running stored procedure..."
cmd.CommandText = "SP_GetOrdersForCustomer"
Set rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)

' Copy the results to cell B7 on the first Worksheet
Set WSP1 = Worksheets(1)
WSP1.Activate
If rs.EOF = False Then WSP1.Cells(8, 2).CopyFromRecordset rs

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing

con.Close
Set con = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = "Data successfully updated."
```

The stored procedure is SP_GetOrdersForCustomer which is:

```vb
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetOrdersForCustomer]
@CustomerID nchar(5)
AS
 BEGIN
    SELECT cst.[CustomerID],
    cst.[CompanyName],
    cst.[ContactName],
    ord.[OrderID],
    ord.[EmployeeID],
    emp.[FirstName],
    emp.[LastName],
    ord.[ShippedDate],
    prd.[ProductName],
    od.[UnitPrice],
    od.[Quantity]
       FROM [Customers] cst,
         [Orders] ord,
         [Order Details] od,
         [Employees] emp,
         [Products] prd
      WHERE ord.[CustomerID] = cst.[CustomerID]
    AND emp.[EmployeeID] = ord.[EmployeeID]
    AND od.[OrderID] = ord.[OrderID]
    AND prd.[ProductID] = od.[ProductID]
    AND cst.[CustomerID] = @CustomerID
     ORDER BY cst.[CustomerID], emp.[EmployeeID], ord.[ShippedDate] DESC
    END
```

I now need to do the stored procedure "Sales by Year" in Northwind which has two date parameters @Beginning_Date and @Ending_Date both are datetime datatypes.

If I put the date 1996-07-01 in Cell F1 and 1996-08-01 in Cell F2 then call the parameter:

```vb
' Set up the parameter for our Stored Procedure
' (Parameter types can be adVarChar,adDate,adInteger,etc)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Beginning_Date", adDate, adParamInput, 10, Range("F1").Text)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Ending_Date", adDate, adParamInput, 10, Range("F2").Text)
```

it does not work.

This is the stored procedure with the dates:

```vb
USE [Northwind]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[Sales by Year]    Script Date:   30/01/2017 22:04:57 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER procedure [dbo].[Sales by Year] 
@Beginning_Date DateTime, @Ending_Date DateTime AS
SELECT Orders.ShippedDate, Orders.OrderID, "Order Subtotals".Subtotal, DATENAME(yy,ShippedDate) AS Year
FROM Orders INNER JOIN "Order Subtotals" ON Orders.OrderID = "Order Subtotals".OrderID
WHERE Orders.ShippedDate Between @Beginning_Date And @Ending_Date
```

And this is the Excel VBA that doesn't work. I tried to modify what I have showed above and I think I should have adDBdate instead of adDate but it fails with "error 3421 application uses a value of the wrong type for current operation":

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim WSP1 As Worksheet
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset


Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
Application.StatusBar = "Contacting SQL Server..."

' Remove any values in the cells and clear a space where we want to dump and put our Stored Procedure's results.
Dim rngRange As Range
Set rngRange = Range(Cells(8, 2), Cells(Rows.Count, 1)).EntireRow
rngRange.ClearContents

' Log into our SQL Server, and run the Stored Procedure
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
cmd.ActiveConnection = con


' Set up the parameter for our Stored Procedure
' (Parameter types can be adVarChar,adDate,adInteger,etc)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Beginning_Date", adDate, adParamInput, 10, Range("J1").Text)
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@Ending_Date", adDate, adParamInput, 10, Range("J2").Text)

'Show some text at the bottom on the status bar
Application.StatusBar = "Running stored procedure..."

'run the stored procedure name in SQL and drop the prefix dbo. it's not needed
cmd.CommandText = "Sales by Year"

'Execute it
Set rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)

' Copy the results to cell B7 on the first Worksheet
Set WSP1 = Worksheets(1)
WSP1.Activate
If rs.EOF = False Then WSP1.Cells(8, 2).CopyFromRecordset rs

'clean terminate
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing

'close off the connection to the SQL database
con.Close
Set con = Nothing

'Did it work ? Then display message at the bottom status bar
Application.StatusBar = "Data successfully updated."

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"? Do you get an error message? Is the data returned not what you think it should be? Slight detour, you should not use the sp_ prefix (or even better no prefix at all). http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: I have added the other stored procedure to show the dates, and the VBA code that I can't get to work, the dates are in cells J1 and J2, I have tried adDBdate and adDate but I get same error for both?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue passing dates the user inputted in excel to SQL Server. What I had to do was convert the excel date format which is where today 2017-04-14 is represented by 42839. To convert 42839 to a date format SQL can ingest I used (dateadd(d, 42839,'1899-12-30')).

It appears that you may be passing Range("J1".text) as '42839'.